# What is special about a space in a Ranorex Regex?

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex

In code generated by Ranorex I have seen that spaces are escaped when text comparison is done on Regex basis:

```
table[@controlid='1008']/?/?/cell[@text~'^This\ text\ has\ spaces']
```

I wondered about that, because in "normal" (all kinds of different Regex I've seen until now), the space is not a special character.

Googling about it I found the [Ranorex XPath site](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/ranorexpath.html) which has the example

> `listitem[@text~'^sample\ 123$']` matches 'sample 123' (use backslash to escape special characters like space)

Following the examples, there is a list of special characters, as there are

```
.
$
|
*
+
?
^
()
[]
[^0-9]
```

It further refers to [Microsoft .NET Regex (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), which sounds reasonable, since Ranorex tests are developed on .NET basis with SharpDevelop.

Being a C# develop for 10 years, I'm pretty sure that a space is not a special character in .NET Regex.

What is special about a space in a Ranorex Regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about it and spaces do not need to be escaped. It's more likely that Ranorex uses  [`Regex.Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx), which escapes the spaces (emphasis mine):

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, **and white space**) by replacing them with their escape codes.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Escape("This text has spaces"));
    }
}
```